# Do I need to use the useCallback hook for a function prop in a functional react component to avoid diffing?

Tags: reactjs

When creating a functional component such as:

```
const SomeParentComponent = ({someMessage, ...otherProps})=>{
    const handleClick = ()=>{
        console.log(someMessage);
    };

    return <SomeComplexComponent onClick={handleClick} ...otherProps />
};
```

My knowledge of React tells me that every single render flow of SomeParentComponent, React is going to perform a diff on the returned contents because the onClick property would have changed on each render flow (newly declared function [handleClick] each time).

To avoid this, you would have to do this instead:

```
...
    const handleClick = useCallback(()=>{
        console.log(someMessage);
    }, [someMessage]);
...
```

This should in theory result in the same callback function instance being used for any one specific 'someMessage' and thus avoid unnecessary diffing.

This is my current understanding of things, and yet no matter where I look online, the only examples of callback inside functional components that I see, simply don't bother with useCallback.

It has reached the point where I am starting to second guess my own knowledge here as possibly flawed.

Can someone tell me if I am correct and almost every example on the internet that I've seen, is just doing it 'less than ideal'?  Or is my knowledge on the subject incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean diffing as in the rendering part. The rendering still is gonna occur. What happens is that [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) creates a memoized version of the function.

So if no dependency changes there is no need to create another instance of said function.

Your confusion must come from the line in the docs:

> This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g. shouldComponentUpdate).

But that refers to a child component that receives the callback as a prop and looks at that prop to check if it should render **(PureComponents and shouldComponentUpdate)**. With useCallback the same function is used (given the dependencies didn't change) thus making the prop not trigger any update.

So, to better answer your question, if you have child components that are:

1. PureComponents
2. Components that have shouldComponentUpdate that check if the callback changed

Then useCallback will help in ensuring the correct behaviour and improve by avoiding unnecessary renders.

Answer (score 0):

Wow.  Forgot I ever even asked this question.  Anyway, am a lot older and wiser now.

To be clear, my assumptions in the question are partially true.
But the fact that usecallback prevents the function ref from changing is irrelevant to that particular component, since the standard functional react component will re-render every time its parent does for any reason.  So having a consistent ref passed to the prop doesn't change that.

The only time this comes into play, is when the component in question is wrapped in 'memo'

const MyComponent = memo(({...props}) => 'This is my component')

When wrapped in memo, it behaves like the old class based pure component, in that it will only allow a render flow on prop or state change.  Now at that point, passing in an anonymous function as a prop would hurt this and cause it to render flow every time the parent does.  And that is where useCallback actually becomes truly useful.